# how to correctly add nested list in numpy docstring in combination with sphinx docstring

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-napoleon

I'm wondering how I can achieve the following. I'm using the numpy docstring style in combination with sphinx autodoc to generate automated documenation. However, I'm struggeling in having a nested list in the output:

```
Attributes
----------
attribute 1: pandas data frame
    * `index:` Array-like, integer valued representing
          days. Has to be sorted and increasing.
    * `dtype:` float64. Value of temperature.
    * `columns:` location description, e.g. 'San Diego'
attribute 2: `int`
    nice and sunny days in California
```

the output of this docstring is complete off. It doesn't recognize the list for attribute 1.

For another thing the function description spans multiple lines:

```
def generate_temp(self, n, freq, very_long_variable_name,
                  type_temp=None, method=None):
```

Also here sphinx doesn't recognize the complete function and treats the second line independently from the first.

What is wrong with my formatting?

Comment: Are you using `sphinx.ext.napoleon` (http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/napoleon.html)?

Comment: @mzjn yes, thats correct, I'm using napoleon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [NumPy docstrings in Napoleon](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/napoleon.html#google-vs-numpy), you need a space on both sides of the colon.  Try this:

```
Attributes
----------
attribute 1 : pandas data frame
    * `index:` Array-like, integer valued representing
      days. Has to be sorted and increasing.
    * `dtype:` float64. Value of temperature.
    * `columns:` location description, e.g. 'San Diego'
attribute 2 : `int`
    nice and sunny days in California
```

I don't know if that will work, as the [example NumPy strings](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/example_numpy.html) indicates that only paragraphs are supported.  It doesn't mention anything about lists.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. I'm really wondering if its possible to include a list in such a case

Comment: Did you at least put a space on both sides of the colon? Also I looked at the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/RobRuana/sphinx-contrib/src/a311ef7908cb1cca880dcc32aae89a297ab21e0c/napoleon/sphinxcontrib/napoleon/docstring.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#docstring.py-28), and it appears that bulleted lists are supported. I think there is an issue with the indent for the second line of the first item, which I just fixed with an edit.